# Kafka zookeeper keep on showing info Message 'Accepted socket connection from /10.xxx.xxx.xxx'

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I was working on existing Kafka but some how it stopped responding to configuration 'retention.ms'.so I installed fresh copy of Kafka 0.8.2.1 and ran it. but it keeps showing info messages like: The IP it shows is valid IP on our Network which produces messages on it. But even its machine is off it keeps showing it

```
[2016-02-18 10:46:10,830] INFO Accepted socket connection from /10.20.xxx.xxx:5988
1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2016-02-18 10:46:10,832] INFO Refusing session request for client /10.20.xxx.xxx:
59881 as it has seen zxid 0x8b47 our last zxid is 0x165 client must try another
server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-02-18 10:46:10,832] INFO Closed socket connection for client /10.20.xxx.xxx:
59881 (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServer
Cnxn)
```

Comment: Do you remember what happened and what (might have) solved it?

Comment: i think i restarted the VM and closed all Kafka clients but that is not perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, the way to make sure Kafka noticed the machine was no longer there, was to restart the machine as well as Kafka.